# Merging Branch back into Main Trunk

Tags: tortoisesvn

What's the best way to merge the branch back into the trunk?  I assume do an SVN merge to your working copy, merge the changes and check back in?  So I'd merge FROM the mainline TO my branch?

Comment: Also, there have been no commits to the mainline trunk since this branch, so I dno't think I need to merge anything into my branch.  I can just I guess repoint and check back into mainline trunk from my branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually check out the head revision of the trunk, merge it with the head revision of the branch and then commit

Comment: fing worked like a charm!!!!  http://weblogs.asp.net/bsimser/archive/2008/05/06/day-to-day-with-subversion.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I usually do the following:

1. merge: trunk -> branch; commit
2. merge: branch -> trunk; commit

This ensures that your branch contains all the most up-to-date changes in trunk and that when you merge your branch back into the trunk, you don't accidentally clobber changes made in the trunk since the last merge.

Since Subversion does not track merges very well, I usually enforce the following commenting scheme:

"$PROJECT_NAME - merge: $BRANCHNAME -> trunk"

or

"$PROJECT_NAME - merge: trunk -> $BRANCHNAME"

Comment: what if the trunk has not had any recent changes since you branched.  THen all you have to do is remerge your branch into mainline trunk right?  So would I do a switch for this or just a merge?

Answer (score 0):

Get an up-to-date working copy of trunk and merge your branch into it, make sure it isn't broken, then commit.